# I can't figure out how to adjust row width and height in XAML Grid (win 8 store app)

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I'm building a simple Xaml app with the windows 8 store. Using the default (file/new/project) grid template, I get a screen that shows about 8 tiles all nicely aligned.  I want to make the tiles a little shorter and wider.  When I do that, it seems that the grid itself remembers the previous side.

Where is that set? How can I set it so my grid flows well once I've changed the individual tile size.  I'm attaching a picture to clarify the problem.  That is, the little nice gaps between tiles seems somehow hard coded to the size I am currently at and I can't figure out where to change that size.

Thanks,[image]

Answer (score 0):

never mind.  I found it.  (width="500" is what is was looking for)

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultGridItemTemplate">
          <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="500" Height="250">
```